# How to print out only the unique words in a tree with in order traversal

Tags: binary-tree, unique, traversal, inorder

The question basically says it all but this is what I have so far

```
void inorder(Node *root)
{
    int come_back_later=0;

    if(come_back_later)
    {
       //part where i print out only the unique words from the tree
    }

    if(root==NULL)
        return;

    inorder(root->left);
    cout<<root->word<<": it's word count is: "<< root->count<<endl;
    inorder(root->right);
```

}

The idea is that I go through the inorder traversal first and print out all the the words instead along with their count. But then I want to later on revisit that traversal and print out only the unique words but I don't know how to create the algroithm code for that. All I know if the word count is 1 then that word has to be unique since it only appeared once in the file. If someone can help me then that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

U need to compare it with all the remaining nodes in the tree. Just make a new array and store words u come across along with the count. On your next traversal instead of checking the count there, check in the array and print if count is 1.